# Aerospike - Query with Multiple Filter parameters

Tags: lua, udf, aerospike

I'm trying to query aerospike using multiple filters taking reference from this [link](https://www.aerospike.com/community/labs/query_multiple_filters.html).

I am able to query aerospike based on the given lua script for 1 filter parameter but stuck up with lua script when have to pass more than 2 filter parameters (for example passing two more parameters like age, gender with password).
This is my first time with lua.

Lua Script:

```
local function map_profile(record)
 return map {name=record.name, password=record.password}
end
function check_password(stream,password)
 local function filter_password(record)
   return record.password == password
 end
 return stream : filter(filter_password) : map(map_profile)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter function can have extra parameters and return a closure which can both access those, while still conforming to the expected stub of one parameter being the record, with a boolean return value.

```
local function filter_password(password)
  return function(rec)
    if rec['password'] and (type(rec['password']) == 'string') and
       rec['password'] == password then
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end

local function map_profile(record)
  return map {name=record.name, password=record.password}
end

function check_password(stream,password)
  return stream : filter(filter_password(password)) : map(map_profile)
end
```

However, the best way to query or scan for multiple filters these days (ever since [release 3.12](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/)) is to use [predicate filtering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html). In the majority of cases (unless you need to compare the values of two of the record's bins to each other in some way) you would skip UDFs and use the [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class (in the Java client, or its equivalent in another). You'd get back only those records that matched the filter, regardless of how complex of an expression you built. See the [examples](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java) in the Aerospike Java client, or the [C](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d9/d10/as__predexp_8h_source.html), [C#](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/T_Aerospike_Client_PredExp.htm) and [Go](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/predexp.go) clients.

Comment: You can similarly extend the mapper, aggregator, and reducer as a closure, as long as their parameters and returned types are expected.

Comment: This long condition `if rec[password] and (type(rec[password]) == 'string') and rec[password] == password then` is equivalent to this one: `if rec[password] == password then`

Comment: And probably this one would be more correct: `return function(rec) return rec.password == password end` as far as I understand the main idea of this code.

Comment: You actually do want to test that the field exists before using it, and that the type is of comparable types. The database is schema free and there's nothing assuring you that the bin (a) exists and (b) has the data type you expect. However, I did had a mistake which I just fixed. Thanks.

Comment: In Lua it is ok to compare "incomparable" types.  You will simply get `false` as a result of comparison.

Answer (score 2):

We developed [SQL wrapper for Aerospike](https://github.com/Spikeify/aerospike-ql), that builds LUA code from your SQL query. It might be helpful to you.